# Set variable to access pic port

Tags: port, pic, microchip

I need to use the same piece of code to read from various devices on different pins on a pic.
The function call determines the device i.e.
Device 1 - port A0
Device 2 - port A1
etc.

In my code I need to change the port to input/output, send data and receive data.
So, in pseudo code I need to do:

function readDevice(deviceNumber)

variableType myPortControlVariable;

variableType myPortVariable;

//Select the device port and control that we are going to use

if(deviceNumber==1)

myPortControlVariable = TRISA0;

myPortVariable = RA0;

if(deviceNumber==2)

myPortControlVariable = TRISA1;

myPortVariable = RA1;

etc...

...in function code

myPortControlVariable = 0; //set to output

myPortVariable = 1; //Write a 1

pause
  myPortVariable = 0;  //Write a 0

etc....

Does anyone know how to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. In almost all situations one does not change the input/output function of a PIC pin in the middle of a program. Normally they are set once at the beginning of the program and never touched again.  Besides, how are you to be sure the PIC and an external device will not both drive the line at the same time and burn something out?
2. In your pseudo code you are reading the state of the input/output register.  I can not imagine a reason for doing this.  You are the one who sets this state.  And this state should not change.  So you already know each pin's input/output value.

I can't tell what you want to do in your pseudo code so that's about all the advice I can give.  Try to write this using real code instead.

Comment: I'll try and explain better: I have 2 one wire sensors one connected to A0 and one connected to A1. I want to use the same code to read each sensor. I don't want to duplicate the same code for both sensors so I want to be able to determine which port to Access depending on which sensorI want to Access. Rather than lots of: if device == 1 then A0 = 1 else A1 = 1 constructions I want to do this once to select the port, allocate it to a variable then use the variable to Access the port.

Also to use a 1 wire device you most definitely do have to change the input/output function of a pin.

Comment: Ah, much better. It sounds like your peripheral uses an I2C interface. You are right, you could switch the direction of a pin to do this. You could also use 2 pins tied together on the PIC. One set to be an open collector driver and the other to sense the line. Then you would tie this node high using a resistor and connect it to your I2C peripheral's data port. Or, a much better solution depending on your resources (i.e. which PIC processor you are using, which compiler you are using, ect) is to use the PIC's hardware and the i2c.h libraries in the compiler's directories.

Comment: He said one-wire, not I-squared-C. Presumably it refers to the Dallas 1-wire protocol which is a completely different beast from I2C

Comment: I thought i2c was ... oh, I see - you are saying clock and data on one line ...  well, we'll have to wait and find out from him ...

Comment: Yes it's a Dallas 1 wire DS18B20 that I'm using. I ended up duplicating the code (I hate doing that, so wasteful) but didn't see a clean option. It would be so much easier to set a variable at the start of the function in an if/then construct and then just use the variable.

Comment: Hum, no real code.  And I don't know which PIC you are using. So it is difficult to comment.

Comment: Hum, no real code.  And I don't know which PIC you are using. So it is difficult to comment. (1) Some PICs have re-programmable pins.  That is, the internal features such as a serial port can be connected to different pins.  My suggestion is to use the same code and the same internal serial port.  But connect it to different pins when talking to different external devices.  (2) When you are ready to send something out, call the same single routine where you test once and only once to decide which peripheral you want to talk to. So your main transmit routine is the same for both devices.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your peripheral uses an I2C interface.

Let's take a look at what Microchip.com has to offer.  If we go here:
http://www.microchip.com/CodeExamplesByFunc.aspx

We can search for several examples of I2C code.  We would have to know exactly which PIC you are using to find the closest matching application note.  Unless we find an exact match, (PIC, compiler, libraries and your physical design) you will have to make adjustments.

I picked this application note:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/CE337%20I2C_MASTER.zip

If you download, unzip this package and open the i2c_master.c file you can see how microchip is communicating using a PIC 24Fxxxx family of processors and the i2c libraries found in the C30 compiler files.  If you have recently put together your PIC SDK, you probably are using the newer XC18 compiler instead.  This also depends on which PIC you are using (So it is important to know.  Otherwise you just have to keep an open mind w.r.t. these suggestions.).  As for switching from the C30 to the newer XC18 compiler, well, I think the code will still work.  But, as I said, you may have to make adjustments.

If you look closely you will see that nowhere in the program is there code to change direction of the PIC's I2C data lines.  That's because this is abstracted from you by the i2c.h libraries in the xc18 compiler files.  Further, most PIC 24Fxxxx class of chips have several I2C modules.  Hardware that is designed into the PIC to handle the I2C interface and generate interrupts.  Using the built in hardware will allow your code to do other things during the slow I2C transactions.

Summing it up:  Yes, you can do all this by hand (I think that was where you were going).  But, depending on which PIC you are using, it can be done much faster in the hardware built into most PIC processors.

Note:  This example (from microchip.com that I am talking about) requires you to pull the I2C clock and I2C data lines running between the PIC and the I2C peripheral up using a 4.7K resistor.  This reminder is written into the comments of the example code - just so you don't forget!  I assume that is because the I2C drivers (not software, but the electronics behind the processor pins) are of "open collector" design.

Apples and Oranges:  If you are an Arduino Uno fan and think this is all way too complex, consider the dark side of the Arduino Uno's simplicity: You are stuck with exactly what an Arduino Uno is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using peripherals that integrate clock and data on one bi-directional line then I don't see a microchip.com example on this page:
http://www.microchip.com/CodeExamplesByFunc.aspx

But you can probably find many examples if you search the web.

If you only want to write your I/O code once you need to abstract it from the hardware.  Everywhere you change, set or clear a pin you could call a method with an formal argument describing which device you are talking to.  Then, in that method, you would hard code which PIN you want to manipulate.  It sounds like you want to hard code many pins in something like a select/case statement.

To address your pseudo code specifically ... I think we need to look at how TRISA0 is defined (this specific code segment is from the p24HJ128GP204.h file - there are many other files where this could come from depending on which PIC you are using):

```
extern volatile unsigned int  TRISA __attribute__((__sfr__));
typedef struct tagTRISABITS {
  unsigned TRISA0:1;
  unsigned TRISA1:1;
  unsigned TRISA2:1;
  unsigned TRISA3:1;
  unsigned TRISA4:1;
  unsigned :2;
  unsigned TRISA7:1;
  unsigned TRISA8:1;
  unsigned TRISA9:1;
  unsigned TRISA10:1;
} TRISABITS;
```

It appears that TRISA0 part of a structure.  Not just a value you can assign to a variable. And it would appear from this line in the same file:

```
#define _TRISA0 TRISAbits.TRISA0
```

You would have to refer to the pin as "_TRISA0" not "TRISA0".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't pass bits in C. Check out this FAQ for more info: http://www.xargs.com/pic/c-faq.html#pinarray

The work-around is therefore to pass a flag into your I/O functions that trigger a switch or if-else at the lowest level:

```
void send_bit (char device,char value) {
    switch (device) {
        case DEVICE_1:
            // output bit value to correct port
            break;
        case DEVICE_2:
            // output bit value to correct port
            break;
    }
}
```

Now with that ugliness out of the way, we can build much cleaner code on top of it:

```
// The following is just a generic example, change bit order etc
// to fit the protocol you're using.

void send_byte (char device, char value) {
    char i;
    for (i=0;i<8;i++) {
        send_bit(device,(value >> i)&0x01);
    }
}

void send_message (char device, char address, char *buffer, char length) {
    char i;
    send_byte(device,address);
    for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
        send_byte(device,buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

The key is to contain the ugliness in only one place - the lowest level I/O function. Then build up much cleaner abstractions on top of it.

---

Additional considerations:

If you're using bi-directional signaling, you should never set the output bit to 1. Doing that can potentially damage either the output buffer of your PIC or the output buffer of other devices if the high values collide.

Instead, bidirectional signaling is typically implemented as open collector circuits with pull-up resistors attached. That way, devices transmits 0 by pulling the voltage down and 1 by setting the output as high-impedance. Therefore, the correct way to communicate with 1-wire devices is to hard code the output pin to 0 and toggle the TRIS bit between output mode (to transmit 0) and input mode (to transmit 1).

On some devices, a small number of I/O pins may have weak pull ups built-in. You may enable that if you don't want to use external pull-up resistors but in my experience it's better to use a small (4.7k?) external pull-up especially if the distance between the two chips is long (anything longer than 0.5 cm?).

Another thing to consider is you may get away with using only one pin to communicate with both devices since only the device with the correct address will respond to your PIC. The only problem is that most 1-wire devices have hard coded addresses so if you're trying to communicate with two identical devices then yes, you'll need to use the trick above to switch pins at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an array of volatile pointers to LAT registers, and maintain arrays with info which bit to set. I wrote this up 16-bit PIC controllers on

See http://www.microchip.com/forums/m794597.aspx

This can also be applied to TRIS registers.